# Postgres sometimes will not start after hard reboot

Tags: linux, postgresql

We have around 100 servers in clients running Postgres with Ubuntu server. 
Sometimes after a hard reboot (eg. power loss) the postgres do not start. To start we have to access the server and type:

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql.service
```

What is the best solution fix the problem automatically without we have to  access the server manually? Is it a good idea a script the checks the postgres startup status and use the start command if necessary?

Best regards